# Как сохранять данные: по 100 постов из 30 тысяч сообществ из вконтакте

Tags: python, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно скачать из вконтакте по 100 постов из 30 тысяч сообществ. Потом мне эту информацию предстоит обрабатывать. Посоветуйте, чем пользоваться для сохранения этих данных, чтобы потом иметь возможность наиболее быстро их опять загрузить?

Comment: Обычные файлы - не вариант?

Comment: Слово big-data не стоит использовать для данных, которые можно в RAM уместить на телефоне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начните с самого простого: используйте SQLite для сохранения и последующих запросов или даже проще как один пожатый json-файл на диск скинуть (как firefox для session recovery делает—минус сжатие).

Pickle и производные форматы неявно поощряют более сложные структуры данных и менее переносимы между версиями программы или на другие языки.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону модуля pickle.

Очень простой и удобный способ сохранять произвольные структуры данных в файл, чтобы потом прочитать их и получить те же структуры.